# Use chi-squared test to determine if sparse categorical variables are collinear

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, multicollinearity

I have two categorical variables:

- Football fans (1 to 5)
- Happiness (1 to 5)

I want to test if these are collinear variables and I have a table  like this:

```
          Football Fan
              1    2    3   4   5
Happiness 1   25   2    0   0   0
          2   2    40   0   0   0
          3   1    5    3   0   0
          4   0    3    1   1   0
          5   0    0    2   5   1
```

If I try to study if they are collinear in R with a chi-squared method

```
tbl = table(df$Football_fan,df$Happines)
chi2 = chisq.test(tbl, correct=FALSE)
```

I get and error:

```
Warning message in chisq.test(tbl, correct = FALSE):
 “Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect”.
```

I think this is because I don't have many observations for the biggest categorical values (I checked other posts about this). But as you can see in the table they are collinear. How can I show that they are collinear with statistical methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem I have grappled with and the solution I currently use is to build the saturated model (model with all variables in it) and calculate the variance inflation factor (vif) to determine which variables may be correlated strongly enough to introduce problems with multicollinearity. Given the VIF or the generalized VIF more specifically, I would use domain knowledge (and tables such as the you constructed) to determine which variables to exclude to reduce the risk of multicollinearity. The VIF is an estimate of how much larger the variance is due to correlation with other variables compared to what it would be if there was perfect orthogonality

Comment: thank you for tour answer! Yes, It is possible to study multicollinearity with VIF and PCA analysis. I did a VIF study and worked well! thanks!